# issues assigned a value to a variable using a property file

Tags: java

hi all i am having an issue, i have a properties file, this stores all the save locations, i get the data from this file by :

```
public void loadProp() {
        System.out.println("Loading properties");
        InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"); //points to a properties file, this will load up destinations instead of having to declare them here
        try {
            configProp.load(in);
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destination"));
            System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("fileList"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("called get username");
        username = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
        System.out.println(username);


    }
```

i then do this to assign the value to destination

```
public String destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");
```

but whenever i use destination i get a null value, however if i use configProp.getProperty("destination") i get the full path, what am i doing wrong here as i want the value to be point to destination as other classes depend on it

EDIT :

```
This class is called on by a command button (web app)

    @ViewScoped
    @ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadController")
    public class FileUploadController {

        public boolean isUploadComplete() { //to enable the next button once finished
            return uploadComplete;
        }

        public void setUploadComplete(boolean uploadComplete) {
            this.uploadComplete = uploadComplete;
        }

        public boolean isUploadComplete2() {
            //to disable the file upload button, this will stop users uploading multiple files and over writing them as only the last file uploaded will be used
            return uploadComplete;
        }

        public void setUploadComplete2(boolean uploadComplete) {
            this.uploadComplete = uploadComplete;
        }
        /*
         public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
         System.out.println("called");
         FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Succesful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
         }
         }
         */
        //
        //Strings for fileUpload
        //oadProp() 
        //public String fileList = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/Directory Files/directoryFiles.txt"; //
        private Properties configProp = new Properties();

        @PostConstruct
        //System.out.println(destinationPDF);
        //System.out.println(destination);
    // Get the username from the login page, this is used to create a folder for each user
        public void loadProp() {
            System.out.println("Loading properties");
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"); //points to a properties file, this will load up destinations instead of having to declare them here
            try {
                configProp.load(in);
                System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destinationPDF"));
                System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("destination"));
                System.out.println(configProp.getProperty("fileList"));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("called get username");
            username = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
            System.out.println(username);


        }
//String destinationPDF = configProp.getProperty("destinationPDF"); Always makes a null no idea why yet
    //private String destinationPDF = configProp.getProperty("destinationPDF");
    public String destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");
    private String username;
    //public static String destination = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/uploaded/"; // main location for uploads//TORNADO ONLY //"D:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/uploaded/"; // USE ON PREDATOR ONLY 
    public static String NewDestination;
    public static String UploadedfileName;
    public static String CompletefileName;
    //
    //Strings for file copy
    //
    //private String destinationPDF = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/"; //USE ON TORNADO//"D:/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/";//USE ON PREDATOR    
    private String NewdestinationPDF;
    public static String PdfLocationViewable;
    private boolean uploadComplete;
    private boolean uploadComplete2;

    //
    public void File() {
```

above is the first bit of code for that class

the output in the console is :

```
INFO: buttonToUploadText invoked
INFO: Loading properties
INFO: D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/pdf/
INFO: D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/
INFO: D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/web/resources/Directory Files/directoryFiles.txt
INFO: called get username
INFO: null
INFO: destination is null
```

Comment: Where are you calling `loadProp`? You're initializing the variable at the point of construction (before any of the body of your constructor gets called) - there's no point in calling `loadProp` afterwards...

Comment: i call loadProp on the start, it is the first thing that gets run when this java class gets called, and yes that was my original question but this is an separate issue of that question

Comment: @user2065929: Show us how you call `loadProp()` _on the start_... This code `public String destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");` get's executed prior to the constructor...

Comment: added above, i call it from a command button and its the first thing that gets run in the class

Comment: @user2065929: The first thing is the constructor. (Default constructor provided by compiler). Prior to the constructor this code is executed `public String destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");` and the properties haven't been loaded at that time.

Comment: ok thanks, how do i get the properties to load first and then execute that code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ordering is off. This is what will happen when your bean is instantiated by the container:

1. Constructor will be called
2. All injected fields will be resolved
3. PostConstruct will be called.

Currently, you are setting the `destination` value ***before*** your properties have been loaded up. A very simple solution to this problem is to simply set the `destination` value in your @PostConstruct handler.

```
@PostConstruct
public void loadProp() {
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
            .getResourceAsStream("config.properties");
    try {
        configProp.load(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");
}
```

One advantage of this method over others is that the `destination` property will be correctly set every time the `loadProp` method is called (as opposed to only once).

Comment: Thanks a lot !, both answers have worked perfectly, but have chosen to use this one, thanks a lot for taking the time to look at my code and help me :)

Comment: @user2065929: would have chosen this one, too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
public String destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");
```

with

```
public String destination;
```

and provide a constructor:

```
public FileUploadController() {
    loadProp();
    this.destination = configProp.getProperty("destination");
}
```

Now, `loadProp()` will be called by the constructor, and you don't have to do it anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot !, thanks a lot for taking the time to look at my code and help me :)